# Python- Replacing a item in a list only replaces the first instance, rather than all instances

Tags: python, list, replace

I'm teaching myself Python at the moment, and am trying to write a 'Hangman' game. The code below is designed to check if a letter is in a list made from the randomly selected word, and if it is replace an _ in another list (made of underscores) with the actual letter. My issue is, that when a letter appears more than once, it will not replace all instances of it, yet as far as I can see from other similar questions, my code should do that. Hope this makes sense and that I've asked in the right way.

EDIT, as suggested: word_list is a list generated from a selected word, so if 'word' is 'hello', word_list becomes ['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
blank_word_list is generated by a for loop through word and replaces each item with '_ ' and ends up as ['*', '*', '*', '*', '_']. If I input 'l', the first 'l' would be replaced but not both. If I then try to input a second 'l' I get an error as python tried to remove 'l' from the letter_mod list, but can't

```
if guess in word_list:
    for n, i in enumerate(word_list):
        if i == guess:
            blank_word_list[n]= i
            print (blank_word_list)
            letters_mod.remove(guess)
            print (letters_mod)
            if ('_') not in blank_word_list:
            game_on = False
            print ("You Win!")
        else:
            guess = input("Guess a letter ")
            guess = str(guess)
```

the guess variable comes from an input, the 'letters_mod' variable is a list with a-z, so the code checks that the input is valid, and it's also supposed to remove any letter that has been guessed from that list. This bit seems to work.

Comment: Your indentation seems to be off, can you please first fix that? Also, what is the output you are getting now?

Comment: Give sample of word_list and output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if guess in word_list: # If the guess is correct
    for n, i in enumerate(word_list):
        if i == guess: # Find the indexes where the letter 'guess' is present
            blank_word_list[n]= i # Replace the underscode with the correct letter
            print (blank_word_list)
            letters.remove(guess)
            print (letters)
            if ('_') not in blank_word_list:
                game_on = False
                print ("You Win!")
            else: # If the game is not finished:
                guess = input("Guess a letter ") # Ask for a new letter
                guess = str(guess)
```

As soon as you find the first correct letter, you ask for a new guess. The logic for determining whether the user has won or a new guess is needed should be outside of the for loop, whose only purpose is to find all letters that the user has correctly guessed.

Assuming you are running an inifite loop, a possible code is:

```
while True:
    if ('_') not in blank_word_list:
        # user wins
    else:
       #  ask for a new guess
    if guess in word_list:
        for n, i in enumerate(word_list):
            # for loop code
```

Comment: I see, that's done it! I was getting confused about the order events would happen, but moving the win condition parts outside seems to have done the trick. Thanks very much.